# MATLAB: hiding nz in sparsity matrix output

Tags: matlab

When plotting a sparsity matrix using `spy` in MATLAB, the text `nz=x`, where `x` is an integer appears at the bottom. This number presumably refers to the number of nonzero elements in the matrix. How can one suppress this output from appearing in the final plot?

The `nz=` text that accompanies sparsity plots can be seen here:[image]

This plot is from the MATLAB documentation on [`spy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/spy.html) (the image URL is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/spy.gif)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way, but you can open the spy.m file:

```
edit spy.m
```

and comment out the xlabel((['nz = '... line

You can even check the nargin, i.e., change your spy's definition and check if you have for example a boolean or not to show nz accordingly...

Hope it helps

Comment: Your answer makes clear that the `nz=` text is simply an `xlabel`; therefore, it can be cleared via the command `xlabel('')`. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah true! More elegant than breaking consistency between your Matlab and others'. Good thinking.

Answer (score 3):

Just overwrite the label with blank:

```
B = bucky;
spy(B)
xlabel('')
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't realized it was an `xlabel` until the response of @gpierris.